# Syntax for declaring defaults

Tags: typescript

I have been experimenting with OO in typescript lately, and have been trying to declare some generic classes.

I am trying to extend a class, and declare defaulted values inside the class itself, but I am running into a syntax error.

Why would my property be read only in this situation?

```
    export interface Heading {
      size: number;
      color: number;
    }

    export class text {
      size: number;
      color: number;
    }

    export class Document extends text {
      H1: Heading = {
        size = 1 // syntax error - Cannot assign to 'Number' because it is a constant or a read-only property.
      };
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two issues.

First, the `color` attribute has to be marked as optional if you are going to exclude it.

```
export interface Heading {
    size: number;
    color?: number;
}
```

Second, you have to use Object notation `:` and not equals.

```
export class Document extends text {
    public H1: Heading = {
        size:  1
    };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want your Document to have default values of size and color, you should write the values as they appear in the extended class `text`:

```
export class Document extends text {
  size = 1;
  color = 1;
}
```

By the way, you code had an issue:

TypeScript compiler really says H1 lacks of color property. So, you either **add it to your class**:

```
export interface Heading {
  size: number;
  color: number;
}

export class text {
  size: number;
  color: number;
}

export class Document extends text {
  H1: Heading = {
    size: 1,
    color: 1,
  };
}
```

or place an optional `?` operator:

```
export interface Heading {
  size: number;
  color?: number;
}

export class text {
  size: number;
  color: number;
}

export class Document extends text {
  H1: Heading = {
    size: 1
  };
}
```